# Flatter iOS build unsupported architecture & another build error when excluding them

Tags: ios, xcode, dart

At first when trying to build the project, which is a very simple app implementing a web view, I found the following error:

```
Error (Xcode): Building for iOS Simulator, but linking in .tbd built for macOS/Mac Catalyst, file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.tbd' for architecture arm64


Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Error (Xcode): Building for iOS Simulator, but linking in .tbd built for macOS/Mac Catalyst, file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.tbd' for architecture x86_64
```

The error originated from a file called OrderedSet in Pods.
At first glance, it seemed like it tries to compile for an unsupported architecture, so I tried to exclude it by excluding both arm64 and x86_64 from OrderedSet, but then it resulted with the following error:

```
Error (Xcode): Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/lesscomplexity/IdeaProjects/Wrklk-App/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/OrderedSet/OrderedSet.framework/OrderedSet'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a
script phase or custom build rule which produces it?
```

It looks as though this file cannot be compiled so it is not generated in the build folder. I've tried to exclude architectures in other areas, and even just one of those architectures at the time, but the same errors still occur.

I've also tried to turn ON/OFF the Build Active Architecture Only option, but with no difference in output.

When I created a new flatter project I get the following error when trying to run for iOS:

```
Error (Xcode): Target debug_universal_framework failed: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:

Error (Xcode): linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
/Users/lesscomplexity/IdeaProjects/untitled3/ios/clang:0:0
```

They all might be connected somehow but I couldn't figure it out. I've tried installing/uninstalling xcode and other components but with no change. I've looked up in various sources online, but still nothing helped. Is there something wrong with my environment? and if so how can I fix it?

EDIT:
After re-installing Xcode to the new version, I got the following error:

```
Error (Xcode): Building for 'iOS-simulator', but linking in dylib (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.0.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.tbd) built for 'macOS macCatalyst
zippered(macOS/Catalyst)'
```